# Excel VBA Find last row number where column "C" contains a known value

Tags: excel, vba

Seeking a method in Excel VBA to Find last row number where column "C" contains a known value.

Comment: we need some code to help you?

Comment: I haven't any code, that's what I'm asking for.

Comment: your asking in the wrong place then.. please read what stackoverflow is about.

Answer (score 8):

This will find the **last** occurrence of *happiness* in column **C**

```
Sub SeekHappiness()
    Dim C As Range, where As Range, whatt As String
    whatt = "happiness"
    Set C = Range("C:C")
    Set where = C.Find(what:=whatt, after:=C(1), searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
    MsgBox where.Address(0, 0)
End Sub
```

To output the row number only, use:

```
MsgBox Mid(where.Address(0, 0), 2)
```

To find the **first** occurrence:

```
Sub SeekHappiness()
    Dim C As Range, where As Range, whatt As String
    whatt = "happiness"
    Set C = Range("C:C")
    Set where = C.Find(what:=whatt, after:=C(1))
    MsgBox where.Address(0, 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: For your find first example, If the first instance is in cell C1, this will find the _second_ instance. Use `after:=C(C.Cells.Count)`

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through the column to find the last occurrence of a value.

```
Sub findLastRow()
  Dim searchValue As String
  Dim endRow As Integer
  Dim lastRowSearchValue As Integer

  searchValue = "testValue"        ''enter your search value
  With Worksheets("sheet1")        ''enter the name of your worksheet
      endRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row   
      For i = 1 To endRow
          If .Cells(i, 3) = searchValue Then
              lastRowSearchValue = i
          End If
      Next i
  End With
End Sub
```

Just replace the value of the variable "searchValue" with whatever is the value you're looking for (maybe change the type of the variable if its not a string) and the Sub will store the index of the last row of the occurrence of the searchValue in the variable "lastRowSearchValue" for further use.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Sub GetRo()
'Either select data or replace selection with your range
    Debug.Print Selection.Find(what:="mysring", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
End Sub
```