# RemoveDuplicaties Function in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

The RemoveDuplicates function in vba removes the second occurrence, I need to keep the second occurrence and delete the first.

the column I am searching through is unsorted, I need to search a specific column for duplicates and if a duplicate is found then the first occurrence needs the entire row to be deleted, keeping the second

this is the code I have so far.

```
Dim overLayWB As Workbook       'Overlay workbook
Dim formattedWB As Workbook     'Formatted workbook
Dim formattedWS As Worksheet    'Current active worksheet (Formatted)
Dim overLayWS As Worksheet      'Worksheet in OverLay
Dim lastRowFormatted As Long
Dim lastRowOverLay As Long

'open Overlay workbook
Set overLayWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents\Overlay.xls") 'Path for workbook Overlay to copy from
Set formattedWS = Workbooks("Formatted").Sheets("Formatted")
Set overLayWS = Workbooks("Overlay").Sheets("Overlay")
Set formattedWB = ThisWorkbook

'Find last row in worksheet Formatted
With formattedWS
    lastRow = .Range("G" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

'Find last row in worksheet OverLay
With overLayWS
    lastRowOverLay = .Range("G" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

'Copy contents of Overlay over to Formatted
Range("E22:BP" & lastRowOverLay).Select
    Selection.Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Formatted").Range("E" & lastRow).PasteSpecial

'Close OverLay Workbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
overLayWB.Close

'Find last row after inserting overlay rows
    With formattedWS
        lastRow = .Range("G" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

'Remove duplicates
    formattedWS.Range("G22:G" & lastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=5, Header:=xlYes
```

Comment: @jeeped this is not the same question as the one marked as duplicate.  I am using the remove duplicated function - the suggested question this duplicates does not.  I am a beginner at VBA so do not understand the code in that question

Comment: a) remove duplicates **always** removed the second; **never** the first so continually asking for it to remove the first makes no sense b) not understanding the code in that solution does not make it any less a duplicate. try to rework the code and if you run into trouble, post a new question showing your new effort and explain what you are having trouble with.

Comment: The question indicates that the user wants to delete the 1st occurrence, if "Remove Duplicates" only keeps the 1st occurrence, then it will not work in this situation. Possibly using "Find", this will find the 1st occurrence, and then you can delete that row. If you are actually trying to find the last occurrence, then you should indicate this. Check this out...[Find Last Occurance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28132471/excel-vba-find-last-row-number-where-column-c-contains-a-known-value)